# Weights updating and estimating training example values in playing checks

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am reading the Tom Mitchell's Machine Learning book, the first chapter.

What I want do is to write the program to play checker with itself, and learn to win at the end. My question is about the credit assignment of a non-terminal board position it encounters. Maybe we can set the value using the linear combination of its feature and randomly weights, how to updates it with LMS rules? Because we don't have the training samples apart from ending states.

I am not sure whether I state my question clearly although I tried to.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't read that specific book, but my approach would be the following. Suppose that White wins. Then, every position White passed through should receive positive credit, while every position Black passed through should receive negative credit. If you iterate this reasoning, whenever you have a set of moves making up a game, you should add some amount of score to all positions from the victor and remove some amount of score from all positions from the loser. You do this for a bunch of computer vs. computer games.

You now have a data set made up of a bunch of checker positions and respective scores. You can now compute features over those positions and train your favorite regressor, such as LMS.

An improvement of this approach would be to train the regressor, then make some more games where each move is randomly drawn according to the predicted score of that move (i.e. moves which lead to positions with higher scores have higher probability). Then you update those scores and re-train the regressor, etc.